# Can I use a conditional with fetch for both a put and delete request?

Tags: if-statement, fetch, httprequest, put

My code editor is saying something is wrong... Is it due to me writing it poorly or is an if-statement with different requests just not possible?

````
changeLikeCardStatus(cardId, like) {
    return fetch(`${this._baseUrl}/cards/likes/${cardId}`, {
      if(like){
        method: "PUT",
        headers: this._headers
      } else {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: this._headers
      } 
    }).then((res) =>
      res.ok
        ? res.json()
        : Promise.reject(`Error! ${res.statusText}`).catch((err) =>
            console.log(err)
          )
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using conditions inside fetch, apply condition before the return statement, and find the needed method and use that method in fetch. In the below code I have added a statement to get the method name using ternary condition. Please modify it according to the language, and try if it is working

```
changeLikeCardStatus(cardId, like) {
methodName = like?"PUT":"DELETE";
    return fetch(`${this._baseUrl}/cards/likes/${cardId}`, {
      
        method: methodName,
        headers: this._headers
     
    }).then((res) =>
      res.ok
        ? res.json()
        : Promise.reject(`Error! ${res.statusText}`).catch((err) =>
            console.log(err)
          )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That makes sense. 
I tired to upvote you but I get this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Welcome @mike. Just try accepting my answer, that would be better :)

Comment: Thanx! @mike. Once you cross 15 reputations. Then you can upvote the answer 